# Add a Link to a xml tag and parse it with jquery

Tags: xml, parsing, jquery, xml-parsing

I can parse the xml with jquery. Now I want the parsed text to be a hyperlink instead of simple text. Below is what I have written.

```
 $(xml).find("customers")
     .each(function(){
          $("#guys").append("<div class="mybox"><a href="+$(this).find('customer_link').text()+"target="_blank">"+$(this).find('customer_company').text()"</a></div>");                                                                                      

});
```

And here is the XML

```
    <customer_company><![CDATA[Google<br>]]></customer_company>
    <customer_link>http://www.google.com</customer_link>

</myguys>

<myguys>

    <customer_company><![CDATA[EMC<br>]]></customer_company>
    <customer_link>http://www.emc.com</customer_link>

</myguys>
</info>
```

I know there is nothing wrong in logic, I think this is just a syntax error with the a tag. Can somebody tell me where I am doing a mistake here and point me to a nice tutorial

Comment: I've edited it for you, but suggest you spend a little more time laying the code out if you post again. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mixing quote styles. Single quoted (`'`) strings can contain unescaped double quotes (`"`) and vice-versa. Having unescaped double quotes in your double-quoted string is breaking your code.

```
$("#guys").append("<div class="mybox"><a href="+$(this).find('customer_link')
ss^   se^       ss^         se^   ss^       se^            ss^           se^   

.text()+"target="_blank">"+$(this).find('customer_company').text()"</a></div>"); 
      ss^     se^    ss^e^            ss^              se^      ss^        se^ 

ss == string start,
se == string end
```

You can see how this creates random undefined references like `mybox`, but doesn't build the string you intended.
Try this:

```
$("#guys").append("<div class='mybox'><a href=" + 
    $(this).find("customer_link").text() +
    "' target='_blank'>" + 
    $(this).find("customer_company").text() + 
    "</a></div>");
```

Alternatively, you can use jQuery to build all the elements and completely avoid having attributes with quotes embedded in your string:

```
 $("#guys").append($("<div />")
                      .addClass("mybox")
                      .append($('<a/>', {  
                          href: $(this).find("customer_link").text(),  
                          target: "_blank",  
                          text: $(this).find("customer_company").text()  
                      })));
```

The `CDATA` in your xml is going to cause jQuery problems because it is parsing the xml like it's html, not according to the xml specs. You may be better off parsing your xml with a plugin like [jParse](http://jparse.kylerush.net/) if you can't remove the `CDATA` and `<br>` from the `customer_company` element.

Comment: Your code puts all the link tags for each a tag. I mean when I click google. It opens http://www.google.comhttp://www.google.com and emc also opens http://www.google.comhttp://www.google.com

Comment: @singularity, it seems to work for me - here's the [fiddle for elements built in jQuery](http://jsfiddle.net/q6WgG/1/) and a [fiddle for the string example](http://jsfiddle.net/NZEuk/)

Comment: @singularity, I noticed a typo in my string example, so it's fixed, and I was referencing `"customer_link"` for the link text in my second example, so I've updated both.

Comment: when I use the first version of your code, I keep on getting the error missing ) after argument list.

Comment: And actually I am using an ajax call to load my xml
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "myguys.xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: myguys
    });
});

Comment: @singularity What is the signature of the `myguys` method? Regarding the error you're getting on the first code section I posted, I'm not sure what would cause that without seeing the code you've put around it. JSLint doesn't flag anything in the code I posted.

Comment: This is all that I have inside my script tags:
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "customerguys.xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: customerguys
    });
});

function customerguys(xml) {
   $(xml).find("customers").each(function(){ 
            
     $("#guys").append("<div class='mybox'><a href=" + 
    $(this).find("customer_link").text() +
    "' target='_blank'>" + 
    $(this).find("customer_company").text() + 
    "</a></div>"); }
 </script>

Comment: @singularity, you're missing a closing brace and parenthesis in your `customerguys` function. Add `});` before the closing brace `}` and that error should go away. You may find [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/) to be a helpful tool if you run into further syntax errors.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at a snippet of your code:

```
$("#guys").append("<div class="mybox">.......
```

You're closing the tags when you possibly don't mean to:

Try this:

```
$("#guys").append("<div class='mybox'>.......
```

You'll need to think a little more carefully, though, as you have some quotes in your string later.

Comment: how does it make a difference in jquery. I knew it is okay to use single or double quotes in Java/C/C++

Comment: The second " closes the string. So, effectievly you have a `mybox` hanging around in the middle of the interpretable code.